# I want to set a square in another one with fixed width and height

Tags: html, css

I have a parent div, and a child div inside of it

CSS

```
.parent {
    background-color: red;
    width: 500px;
    height: 300px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
.child {
    background-color: yellow;
    width: 200px;
    height: 100px;
}
```

now I want to set child exactly in middle of parent without changing width and height, how can I do that? thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figure it out myself, I just needed to position:overflow; parent, then with some margin thing we can center the child in middle.

Answer (score 0):

Here's one solution, I'm not sure it fits your needs though:

```
.parent {
    background-color: red;
    width: 500px;
    height: 300px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.child {
    background-color: yellow;
    width: 200px;
    height: 100px;
    /* changes */
    top: 100px;
    position: relative;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/BApWV/)

Comment: well, basically with not using position:relative, thanks anyway

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be what you wanted i think

http://jsfiddle.net/kbPV7/7/

```
.parent {
    background-color: red;
    width: 500px;
    height: 300px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    position:relative;
    display:block;

}
.child {
    background-color: yellow;
    width: 200px;
    height: 100px;
    position:absolute; top:50%; margin-top:-50px;
    left:50%; margin-left:-100px;
}
```